# Why is Django (1.8.3) migrations dropping fields in migration when they're still in the model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I went to add a text field to a model in my django app, made, applied my migrations then all of a sudden, I have tests failing left and right. Turns out, the migration decided to drop a field that still exists in my model.

Before going on, some of the relevant code.  First, the effected model:

```
class CandidateProfile(models.Model):

    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name="candidate_profile", null=True, blank=True)
    facebook_url = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    website = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    primary_email = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    party = models.ForeignKey(PoliticalParty, related_name="candidate_party", null=True, blank=True)
    uploaded_picture = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    ref_id = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=50, default="")

    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

The field I added was `facebook_url`.  Prior to this migration, app working, tests passing, etc. The migration that was generated is:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('users', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='candidateprofile',
            name='party',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='candidateprofile',
            name='facebook_url',
            field=models.CharField(default=b'', max_length=200),
        ),
    ]
```

The fix itself is simple enough, I can roll back my migration, and manually remove the `migrations.RemoveField`. Unit tests did what they were supposed to do in letting me know I screwed something up, but I still get worried about something like this getting through to production, losing data and having to restore from a backup.

My question is: why does Django think that the field should be removed even though, it's clearly present as a foreign key in the model?

**Edit:** After the field was deleted, I tried changing properties on the `party` attribute to see if whatever diff-ing mechanism Django uses will pick it up.  No dice, changing `related_name`, `null`, or `blank` didn't do anything. Running `makemigrations` detected no changes.

Also, foreign key model for reference:

```
class PoliticalParty(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length="100")
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length="255")
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length="20")
    ref_id = models.CharField(max_length="50", default="", db_index=True)

    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you 'shadowed' the field, by creating an attribute or method with the same name.

```
class CandidateProfile(models.Model):
    party = models.ForeignKey(PoliticalParty, related_name="candidate_party", null=True, blank=True)

    def party(self):
        """This method will replace the model field"""
        return ''
```

If you didn't do this, then please try to provide instructions that can recreate the issue (preferably with the latest point release 1.8.7). Dropping an existing field is a very serious data loss issue, and the Django developers would take it very seriously.

Comment: Yup, that is exactly what I did.  Updated my naming convention for the getter methods, and no more issues.  Thanks, that was driving me nuts.